# C Server: "connect() failed: Connection refused" Error

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Going through TCP/IP Sockets in C

And I'm trying to use the TCP Echo Client sample code given but I keep getting a `connect() failed: Connection refused` Error.

TCPEchoClient.c
http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/code/TCPEchoClient.c

TCPEchoServer.c
http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/code/TCPEchoServer.c

Comment: i know obvious question, but is your server running?

Comment: yea, can port number cause this?

Comment: yes it can. How are your running the server? Do you have 2 terminals open? a) Run the `EchoServer.c` then run client. Do you get that error?

Comment: Two terminals open and yes I run them in that order.

Comment: what is the port number you are providing ?

Comment: yeah what port number and host your providing?

Comment: greater than 1025 like 1080.

Comment: I Presume the order of execution is server followed by client.. use htons for your port # provided

Comment: Things you can try: 1. give server address 0.0.0.0 (means ANY IPv4 interfaces) 2. after you run the server run `netstat -a` and find the port which you listening on, copy and past the line, it can tell which interface you listening on.

Comment: ^Your first advice did the trick. Thanks!